# For each implementation through SSAS 2005 MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have this MDX expression in the Calculated member

```
(sum([Time Code].[Time Code Group Code],[Measures].[Event Duration])-SUM([Time Code].
[Time Code Group Code].&[MACHINE DELAY],[Measures].[Event Duration]))/(sum([Time Code].
[Time Code Group Code],[Measures].[ Event Duration]))
```

I want to perform this operation on records who have [Time Code] category as"Down"

i.e

```
[Time Code].[Time Code Category].&[Down].
```

How should I include this filter so that the calculation is performed only on records which have Category as DOWN.

Is there FOR each concept in MDX . Please guide on how should I proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The [MDX Generate function](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Generate.html) is the equivalent in MDX of for each. However you can't use it for sum. In icCube you could use [functions](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Declared%20Functions.html) to solve this, for ssas I'd use sets :

```
WITH
  SET [MyFilterSet] as Filter( [Time Code].[Time Code Category], <<condition>> )
...   sum( [MyFilteredSet], [Measures].[Event Duration] )
```